# I'm setting global cookies, but can't seem to access them on subsequent page loads

Tags: javascript, cookies, path, get, global

So I've been searching for the answer to this over the past couple days.  This has been my first foray into cookies, so I hope this will be an easy one for you guys.  I have a website that asks the user if they want to use the mobile version of the site and stores their response in a cookie so that next time they visit, they're automatically taken to their preferred version.  On the mobile site however, I provide a link back to "/desktop.html" on the desktop site which resets their preference to the desktop version of the site and then loads the corresponding desktop version of the page they were on on the mobile site.  That's all well & good but I quickly discovered that the cookie plan was not working.  The user would automatically be redirected back to the mobile site.  I discovered that this is because "desktop.html" was at the root level of the site and all the other pages were in subdirectories.  So I read that you can make cookies global by appending ";path=/;" to the cookie.  I did that to all my pages.  However, I kept getting bounced back to the mobile site despite emptying my cookies from the browser and starting afresh (and I even kept getting asked for my preference each time I went to the desktop site despite setting a cookie each time), so I decided to check the cookie value by putting it in an alert in the pages in the subdirectories and each time any of the pages in the subdirectories are loaded, the cookie has been null/empty.  If I remove ";path=/;", then the cookies I access have the values I'd set on a previous page load and everything works except for the explicit reset in /desktop.html.  I figure I must not be accessing the "global" cookie I'd previously set.  All the pages I'd found say to set a global cookie using that ";path=/;" string, but none of the pages I've been able to find seem to tell me how to access it on subsequent page loads - or I'm just too much of a noob to realize I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code in /desktop.html

```
  <body style="background: rgb(165, 183, 156); margin: 0pt;" onload="document.cookie = 'desktop; path=/';alert('Preference saved. To get back to the mobile site, click the mobile icon in the bottom left corner.');window.location.href='index.html';">Desktop Preference Saved</BODY>
```

And here's the code that's in all the pages in the subdirectories:

```
  <body style="background: rgb(165, 183, 156); margin: 0pt; " onload="onPageLoad();if(document.cookie.length != 0){if(document.cookie.match('mobile') && isMobile.any()){window.location.href=getMobileURL()}}else if(isMobile.any() && confirm('Go to mobile version of site?\nNote: menu navigation on the regular website does not work on a touch screen.')){window.location.href=getMobileURL();document.cookie = 'mobile; path=/';}else{document.cookie = 'desktop; path=/';if(isMobile.any()){alert('Preference saved. To get to the mobile site, click the mobile icon in the bottom left corner.');}}" onunload="onPageUnload();">
```

I don't think they're relevant, but let me know if you need to see the functions getMobileURL() and isMobile.*.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Aren't you basically deleting the cookie by not setting a value? `document.cookie = 'desktop=true;...`

Comment: I'm not sure. If not providing a value deletes the cookie, then why does the cookie work when I do not append ";path=/;"? I'll try setting true though and see what happens.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't think it would work, but it did!  I had thought that the cookie was a simple string and that I could set/get/&parse however I wanted.  Still, it seems strange that it lets me set the cookie as just a name without a value and it works, but if you append properties to it, it deletes it...

Comment: Can you add it as an answer? I can't answer my own question for another 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not set a value, that cookie is being set to be deleted, that is why nothing is being read on the next page. Set a value and it will work.

```
document.cookie = 'desktop=true;...
```

Cookies explained in depth [on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).